# Passing self as an argument to a method

Tags: swift

When we pass an instance of an object as an argument to a method, which is defined inside that object like in the code below, does it create a retain cycle?

```
 self.someMethod(self)
```

Comment: What's the point of passing self to a function inside that exact class?

Comment: @the4kman, just curious

Comment: It won't. FWIW every property/local parameter that you pass to it, is already `self.property` so no need to worry.

Comment: No, not by itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you reference an instance method of your class:

```
class FooBar {
  func foo() {
    print("Foo")
  }
  func bar() {
    self.foo()
  }
}
```

The "self" is implied, and the compiler doesn't need it. Even if you use `foo()` without the `self.`, it still references self implicitly.

No there is no retain cycle, since you are calling from one instance method to another instance method on the same object.

### EDIT:

Where self gets you in trouble is in "escaping" closures. An escaping closure is a closure that is passed to another object that takes a strong reference to it. Completion handlers are usually escaping closures.

So, when you call a function that takes a completion handler and that completion handler is an escaping closure, the other object takes ownership of the closure.

Now, if the closure uses self, it means the closure also owns "self"

```
typealias completionHandler = () -> ()

class AClass {
  lazy var someOtherObject = SomeOtherObject()
  var value: Int = 0
  func callClosure() {
      someOtherObject.doSomething(completion: {
          self.foo = self.foo + 1
      }
  }
}

class SomeOtherObject {
    var myCompletionHandler: () -> ()
    func doSomething( completion: @escaping completionHandler) {
       myCompletionHandler = completion
       //pretend there is code here to call an async method and invoke completion
    }
}
```

The above use of self **does** cause a retain cycle. Here's how:

And instance of `AClass` creates an object of type `SomeOtherObject` and keep a strong/owning reference to it. The `SomeOtherObject` won't go away as long as the instance of `AClass` lives.

When we call `callClosure()`, we pass in a completion handler. The SomeOtherObject takes ownership of the closure.

Now, since the code of the closure references `self`, the closure takes ownership of `self`. We now have a 3-way retain cycle between the AClass object, which owns the `SomeOtherObject`, the `SomeOtherObject`, which owns the closure, and the closure, which owns the `AClass` object.

You can fix the retain cycle by adding a "capture list" to the closure. That is a list of variables that the closure uses that should be held weakly. That modified code might look like this:

```
func callClosure() {
  //the `[weak self]` capture list below makes self weak inside the closure
  someOtherObject.doSomething(completion: { [weak self] in  
      ///use a guard to map weakSelf to strongSelf if it isn't nil, or return
      //if self has been deallocated and is now nil.
      guard let strongSelf = weakSelf else { return }
      strongSelf.foo = strongSelf.foo + 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course. You are right, since self is just an implicit instance property of an object, and is exactly  equivalent to that object. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I explain how `self` **can** cause a retain cycle when used in the body of an escaping closure.

Comment: Great explanation. Although, I'm programming in Swift for a quite long period of time, I still have some problems noticing retain cycles while writing a code. Hope, I'll overcome that. Anyway, thank you for this great example.